# has_many association in rails not returning the child rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :Department_Id, :DepartmentName,:LocationID
set_primary_key :Department_Id 
has_many :Employee

end
```

---

rails console:

```
dept=Department.find(50)
dept.Employee 
SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees` WHERE `employees`.`Department_Id` IS NULL
```

why it is appending the where clause with NULL, i was expecting to see 50. What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby, a variable beginning with a capital letter is a constant variable. Your code should be changed to this:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :department_id, :department_name,:location_id
has_many :employees

end
```

UPDATE: I just gave some examples. You need to change all variables, database column names and so on accordingly. Please make sure everything is comply with the rule: constant variables begin with capital letter and local variable, instance variables are all in down case, in which words are separated with dash.

If your code complies with the rule, you don't have to call `set_primary_key` and set `foreign_key` for belongs_to association.

Comment: I changed as recommended but still no luck

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :department_Id, :departmentName,:locationID
set_primary_key :department_Id 
has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :employeeid, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :jobcode, :salary, :department_id
set_primary_key :employeeid 
belongs_to :department, :foreign_key => "department_id"
end

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow proper conventions, variable with capital letters mean constant variables, try as follow

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :Department_Id, :DepartmentName,:LocationID
  set_primary_key :Department_Id 
  has_many :employee

end
```

or even much better if you do

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :department_id, :department_name,:location_id
  set_primary_key :department_id 
  has_many :employee

end
```

Comment: I changed as recommended but still no luck <br/>

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base<br/>
attr_accessible :department_Id, :departmentName,:locationID<br/>
set_primary_key :department_Id <br/>
has_many :employees<br/>
end<br/>
<br/>
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base<br/>
attr_accessible :employeeid, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :jobcode, :salary, :department_id<br/>
set_primary_key :employeeid <br/>
belongs_to :department, :foreign_key => "department_id"<br/>
end<br/>
 dept.employees<br/>
Employee Load SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees` WHERE `employees`.`department_id` IS NULL